# Map not updating elements on change of state

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a web App on React and I'm having some issues mapping an array when the state changes.

Right now what happens is that I have a button which calls the **App product** function which adds a product to the array **quote.productos**, this is working just fine (whenever I print **quote** on console it has the correct amount of products), then I'm mapping this array so I can show it to the user, the problem comes here because the button updates the view only the first time that is used.

**Render:**

```
    render() {
    return ( 

        < div id = "products" > 
            <div className="quoteBG">
                <div className="quote">
                   { this.state.quote.productos.map((objProd) => 
                         < div key = {objProd.id} className = "review"> 
                              <img src = {objProd.url} /> 
                                   <h2> {objProd.name}</h2>  
                          </div>)}
                </div>
            </div>
           { this.state.products.map(product =>
           <div key = {product.id} className = "product" >
               <h2> { product.name }</h2> 
               <button className = "addProduct" onClick = {() =>{this.addProduct(product)}} > Add product </button>
               </div>)
        } </div>);
 }
}
```

(Yo can see the map function under the div with className="quote" the form)

**Add Product**

```
  addProduct(prod) {
        const newPro = this.state.quote.productos.concat(prod);
        this.state.quote.productos = newPro;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            quote: this.state.quote
        }));
        console.log(this.state.quote);
    }
```

In addition the function is binded in the constructor of the class:

```
 this.addProduct = this.addProduct.bind(this);
```

**(EDIT) Resume** So a little resume of what is happening: I use the button: the view gets updated with the product added, I use the button a second time: the object gets updated but the view doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that React State is immutable, so you can't modify it (actually you can, but that is not detected as 'change'), so you need to make 'new state'.

Your code should look something like this:

```
addProduct(prod) {
    const newPro = this.state.quote.productos.concat(prod);
    const quote = Object.assign({}, this.state.quote, {productos: newPro});
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        quote: quote
    }));
    console.log(this.state.quote);
}
```